# Content of a nested array is not saved via mongoose to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having trouble saving the content of a nested array via json and mongoose to my MongoDB.
It's an exercise app. The idea is to have one Entry, containing several rounds (array of objects), which in turn contain several exercise entries (array of objects).

Mongoose Schemas:

```
var ExerciseEntrySchema = mongoose.Schema({
"exercise_entries" : [
    {
        "ex_name" : String,
        "distance" : Number,
        "distance_unit" : String,
        "weight" : Number,
        "ex_reps" : Number,
        "cal" : Number,
        "ex_time" : Number
    }
]});

var EntrySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    "wod_date" : Date,
    "round_entries" : [
        {
            "round_nr" : Number,
            "exercise_entries" : [ExerciseEntrySchema]
        }
    ],
    "entry_time" : Number,
    "entry_rounds" : Number,
    "entry_comment" : String
});
```

My post route looks like this:

```
app.post("/entries", function (req, res) {
    var newEntry = new Entry({
        "wod_date":req.body.wod_date,
        "entry_comment":req.body.entry_comment,
        "entry_time":req.body.entry_time,
        "round_entries":req.body.round_entries,
        "entry_rounds":req.body.entry_rounds});
    newEntry.save();
});
```

On post a MongoDB entry is saved but the exercise_entries-Array is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks

Mica

Comment: Can u do console.log(req.body) and tell me what it shows.

Comment: '{ wod_date: '2017-02-02',
  round_entries: 
   [ { round_nr: '1', exercise_entries: [Object] },
     { round_nr: '2', exercise_entries: [Object] } ],
  entry_time: '0',
  entry_rounds: '2',
  entry_comment: '' }'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you've got a schema definition that creates an array of arrays for the exercise entries. In the parent Entry schema, you are creating an array of round_entries which has an array of ExerciseEntrySchema objects **which have an array of exercise entries themselves**. I think you just need to simplify your schema definitions so that ExerciseEntrySchema is *just the schema of a single entry*. Here is what I would use:

```
var ExerciseEntrySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    "ex_name" : String,
    "distance" : Number,
    "distance_unit" : String,
    "weight" : Number,
    "ex_reps" : Number,
    "cal" : Number,
    "ex_time" : Number
});

var EntrySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    "wod_date" : Date,
    "round_entries" : [
        {
            "round_nr" : Number,
            "exercise_entries" : [ExerciseEntrySchema]
        }
    ],
    "entry_time" : Number,
    "entry_rounds" : Number,
    "entry_comment" : String
});
```

For the above, a resulting sample document would look like this:

```
{ 
    wod_date: '2017-02-02', 
    round_entries: [ 
        { 
          round_nr: '1', 
          exercise_entries: [
              {
                  "ex_name" : "Swimming",
                  "distance" : 1.5,
              },
              {
                  "ex_name" : "Running",
                  "distance" : 0.5,
              },
          ]
        },
        { 
          round_nr: '2', 
          exercise_entries: [
              {
                  "ex_name" : "Running",
                  "distance" : 1.5,
              },
              {
                  "ex_name" : "Running",
                  "distance" : 1.8,
              },
          ] 
        } 
      ], 
      entry_time: '0', 
      entry_rounds: '2', 
      entry_comment: '' 
  }
```

Comment: Ah yes. I got confused with the whole array nesting. Many thanks @SylonZero for disentangling this whole mess.